# What architecture should I choose for Android GSI?

Tags: android

What file should I choose to download for 32-bit ARM - 64- bit binder architecture devices?

[image: more details]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want support for Google Mobile Services (like core, play store, etc.) then go for **ARM64+GMS**, otherwise **ARM64** should be enough.